# RegEnumValue returns different buffer size in Vista compatibility mode

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, registry

I have a very weird issue when my application is run under "Windows Vista Compatibility mode" (right-click the EXE, enable compatibility mode and select windows vista).

The issue is the return buffer length value from the "RegEnumValue" function returns a different value.

For example, with a registry value of "Zoom Player MAX" (15 characters):

With compatibility mode diabled, RegEnumValue's "lpcbData" field return a value of 16 (including the trailing null termination).

With compatibility mode enabled, RegEnumValue's "lpcbData" field return a value of 15 (doesn't include the trailing null termination).

Is there a work-around/patch for this that doesn't require changing my string conversion code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should not matter. When reading from the Registry using low-level classic functions, you must be able to handle strings with and without null-terminators:

[Beware of non-null-terminated registry strings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040824-00/?p=38063)

The easy way to do this is to secretly allocate one extra character that you don't tell the API about when reading, and then append the `'\0'` character to the end of however many characters it returns.

Newer functions like [`RegGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) handle this for you.